# CSS - Odd Placement in Firefox with background-image

Tags: css, firefox

I have created what I feel is a very, very good and simple "checkbox" CSS that I am using on my site now. It uses no javascript and is extremely succinct, and it is working in all browsers except Firefox. I am getting strange placement behavior of the `div` layer that is intended to show the background image...

I have prepared a `jsFiddle` that illustrates this behavior, and any insight would be appreciated. I am really confused about what could be wrong.

## [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ciel/cfwL3/)

I have also prepared a simple screenshot that demonstrates the difference side by side
[image: Image Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add position:relative here:

```
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + label { ... }
```

and then `top:0; left:0;` here:

```
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + label:before { ... }
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/cfwL3/9/

Comment: Yes! This was it! Thank you, it was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the `top` property for the `position:absolute`.

```
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
   position: absolute;
   left:0px;
   top:0px;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/ciel/cfwL3/**

Comment: Yes! This was it! Thank you, it was driving me crazy! I awarded the credit to the one who posted it first, but both of you are correct. Thank you again.